# Installing Biztalk 2016 with AS/2 but without BAM

Tags: azure, biztalk, biztalk-2016

We're trying to install Biztalk 2016 on a VM in Azure. We need AS/2, but that's about all. The configuration program seems to support AS/2 without BAM (see image, enabling BAM is not required by the user interface here):

[image: Biztalk AS/2 config tab]

Unfortunately the installation/configuration fails for Biztalk EDI/AS2, complaining that it needs BAM. We can complete the installation successfully by adding BAM, but that adds overhead including two databases and a SQL Server component (integration services) that must be installed on the Biztalk server. This is Azure, so the overhead has a direct cost.

Is it possible to work around this limitation and install AS/2 without bringing in BAM, or is it a hard dependency not shown clearly by the installation program?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can configure AS2 without BAM, but BAM is specifically required for the EDI/AS2 Runtime Status Reporting feature since it is based on BAM.

*You really should be using EDI/AS2 Runtime Status Reporting*, otherwise, your only diagnostic path is manually digging through Tracking.

As for overhead, it's not something I would have even considered.  Azure VM's are billed by the hour, regardless of CPU usage so with or without SSIS doesn't matter.

Comment: Then how? We did not select status reporting, yet the installation fails. Clicking apply without BAM does not work. As for cost it does matter if the overhead means we need to use a larger machine.

Comment: You will absolutely *not* need a larger machine to include BAM/SSIS.

Comment: What message are you getting?  The dependency is on Status Reporting and I definitely recall the converse message, to install BAM to enable Status Reporting.

Comment: Unfortunately the log files are gone and as we proceeded by installing BAM as a workaround I can't reproduce. We did get the same error on two different machines (one VM and one physical server) though. I'll see if I can reproduce it again in order to get the logs. It logged an error complaining about BAM being required, but I don't remember the exact words.

Comment: @user2612030 Sure, but you're worrying about something that is simply not the case.  Installing SSIS and BAM will have 0 negative effect and Status Reporting is a *huge* benefit.